# Errors during binding View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

During binding my view to viewmodel I receive two errors:

```
Error   1   ''local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 12, position 7.' XML is not valid.   
Error   2   The attachable property 'Source' was not found in type 'Navigator'.
```

I'm quite new in `WPF`. I received some code from other person and order to rewrite the rest of a code in a same manner. The same code I'm using is working on the sample view I got.

Part of view xamls.

```
 <Page x:Class="XYZ.Views.Pages.EulaPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="640"
  Title="EulaPage"
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls" 
  Initialized="EulaPage_Initialized"
  KeepAlive="True"
  local:Navigator.Source="{Binding}">
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:EulaPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

and ViewModel:

```
class EulaPageViewModel :ObservableObject, INavigable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }

    private ICommand acceptRadioButton_Checked;

    public ICommand AcceptRadioButton_Checked
    {
        get
        {
            if (acceptRadioButton_Checked == null)
            {
                acceptRadioButton_Checked = new RelayCommand(
                    param => Accept(),
                    param => (true)
                        );
            }
            return acceptRadioButton_Checked;
        }
    }
    private void Accept()
    {
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Can you review my parts of a code and tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Duplicate? Huh for me those are two completely different questions

Comment: no, both questions describe the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use below menioned code

```
<Page x:Class="XYZ.Views.Pages.EulaPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="640"
  Title="EulaPage"
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls" 
  Initialized="EulaPage_Initialized"
  KeepAlive="True">
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:EulaPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

if your EulaPageViewModel class in Viewmodel Folder then

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ.ViewModel"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple mistake you have pasted the lines containing `local:` form another file and did not define the prefix in your header just open that file and find line like:

```
xmlns:local="some reference"
```

it will be in root tag of that file.

This line is an equivalent of `using namespace` C# construct.